# ubuntu causing errors while booting

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot

This problem started when i accidentally format the drive in which ubuntu was installed, now every time i start my laptop i am presented with this screen:-
check link:-
[click here](http://postimg.org/image/6m1zxsx67/)

Now i have to type exit then it goes it this screen:-
[click here](http://postimg.org/image/4f2tco7o9/)

After selecting windows 8 i actually land on booting windows 8.

Now I have windows 8 installed only, no sign of ubuntu as i mentioned i formatted the drive.
So i want to get rid of these things so my laptop directly boots to windows 8.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like you could change the boot order, or follow [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287434/making-windows-boot-loader-the-default-instead-of-grub-2) instructions, which basically say boot from the installation disk, and hit the startup repair button.

Comment: I don't have any installation disk, windows 8 was pre installed on my laptop with no windows installation disk

Comment: @dann_ Then try my first solution and change the boot order so that it defaults to the windows drive.

Comment: Got it,Well thanks, for giving me right direction.Grateful to you.